# What's the quickest way to update to the most recent (stable) Elixir release?

Tags: elixir

I'm wondering if there is a command to update Elixir. Here's how I updated to Elixir 1.3 ...

In terminal:

```
brew unlink elixir
```

and then

```
brew install elixir
```

Is there a way to accomplish this update with one terminal command?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run:

```
brew update && brew upgrade elixir
```

Comment: assuming homebrew is up to date can I just run `brew upgrade elixir`?